# How to perform anonymous authentication?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I always thought that acegi security is the same as spring security 3.0... but It seems to be wrong.

Unfortunately I was unable to find any acegi security docs.

I need to have an anonymous user with special role assigned into Security Context what I found about that was [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#anonymous).

But there's no `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` in ACEGI - only `AnonymousProcessingFilter`. But how should I call it's id?

I tried this code:

```
<bean id="anonymousAuthFilter"
      class="net.sf.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter">
    <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
    <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"
      class="net.sf.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
</bean>
```

But I get nothing in my Security Context before I actually login. And that's bad=(

Any ideas?

Comment: You should look at spring 2.0 documentation, which is closest to acegi - http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/anonymous.html

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "get nothing in SecurityContext". Can you add code to show how are you using SecurityContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acegi security is the old name of spring security. (in 2.0 or older I can't remember, it is to long ago)

I strongly recommend to use Spring Security 3.0. Attention: The Package Names and Jar Structure was Changed between Spring Security 3.0 und Spring Security 2.0.

So if you have current documentation you will need to translate it back to 2.0. This Blog [Spring Security 3.0.0.M1 Released](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/06/03/spring-security-300m1-released/) describe the changes.